# Can loading="lazy" be used on <source>

Tags: html

I know I can use `loading="lazy"`on `<img>` and `<iframe>` for browser native lazy loading, but can I also use this attribute on `<source>`?  I cannot find related documentation.

Something like this:

```html
<picture>
<source srcset="/image.webp" type="image/webp" loading="lazy"/>
</picture>
```

Comment: why dont you use just `img` if you have just 1 image

Comment: Because I want to add fallback image for webp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it can't be used on source, because a `<picture>` element has to have one `<img>` element inside. This `<img>` can have the lazy attribute. The browser then figures out on its own (at least I hope it does) which of the source tags it should lazy-load.

Description of `picture` [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture)

> The HTML  element contains zero or more `<source>` elements and one `<img>` element to offer alternative versions of an image for different display/device scenarios.

So the correct code to lazy-load a source should be:

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="/media/examples/surfer-240-200.jpg"
            media="(min-width: 800px)">
    <img src="/media/examples/painted-hand-298-332.jpg" alt="" loading="lazy"/>
</picture>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cloned was correct - if using picture to wrap around sources, the last element should be a fallback img tag. The browser uses the img 'alt' and the 'loading="lazy" to feed into these sources.

Example, if any of these images are fetched, they'll be done so in a lazy manner:

```
<picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 0)" srcset="image/bike-480.jpg">
    <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="image/bike-900.jpg">
    <source media="(min-width: 1200px)" srcset="image/bike-1300.jpg">
    <img loading="lazy" src="image/mage/bike-900.jpg" alt="man riding a blue bicycle">
</picture>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).